# How to migrate data directory of opengeo geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite

How to migrate data directory of geoserver in  opengeosuite 3.1 to stand alone geoserver version 2.5.1. Is it to copy data directory and restart the server only or any thing else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Betwween two different stand alone Geoserver's data directory migration available here
   [Migration of data directory betwwen geoserver's](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/migrating.html)

Comment: It's ok for stand alone versions , I need from opengeosuite3.1(opengeo) to stand alone geoserver..